# Can I have a Qt project without mainwindow?

Tags: qt, qwidget, qdialog, qmainwindow

I'm starting a new `Qt project`. Is it mandatory to have a `mainwindow` in my project?

I only have `qdialogs` and `qwidgets`as I don't need a toolbar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not necessary to have a QMainWindow. A QApplication is enough to get Qt objects rolling. A QWidget that has no parent automatically becomes a standalone window, also known as top-level window.